# regex to search for with space or without space in chain?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to write a regex that searches for a series of items. However, One of the projects that I am using the search to find does not follow a standard naming convention all the way through so I am having issues consolidating my regex search small enough.

Here is an example.

I have

Master Project
Building Project
School Project Phase 1
School Project Phase 2
SchoolProject

Right now I have the following as my regex.

(^Master Project|^Building Project|^School Project ([]A-Z))

This works on everything EXCEPT on the single word schoolproject. I tried adding in ? between school and Project after the white space but that did not seem to help. I tried a lookaround and lookaround negative but I am not really able to get it to work with either method.

Comment: `(School ?Project)` should work... http://regexr.com/3cenl

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your "project names" are all on one line as shown in the example:

```
(Master Project|Building Project|School ?Project([ A-Za-z]* [0-9])?)
```

This also assume that the "Phases" come after the rest of the name, e.g. School Project Phase 1, not Phase 1 School Project.

If each "project name" is in its own string, you can add back in the `^` before "Master", "Building", etc.

http://regexr.com/3ceno